# Match phone number not preceded by text

Tags: java, regex

I try to use negative lookbehind regex to match phone numbers not preceded by text:

```
Tel (123) 456-7890
```

What I have so far matches both cases, with and without preceding text, 
not sure why.

```
(?<!Tel )(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more sample strings? Is `Tel` always at the start of string?

Comment: yes, it's always at the start of string.

Comment: @dandemmo See my answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead at the start of the pattern:

```
^(?!Tel)(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}
^^^^^^^^
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/2HjwWq/1).

---

Or anchor the negative lookbehind:

```
^(?<!Tel )(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}
^^^^^^^^
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/2HjwWq/2)